# Difference between Tests and Coverage steps on CI Servers

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, code-coverage

I'we just start playing with setting `thresholds` when I run my `coverage` trying to force our team to apply to dedicated threshold standards.
My question is this, is there any need for separate `tests` and `coverage` steps? To me it looks like they are doing exactly the same thing? I was thinking of emerging those two steps into on `tests-coverage` step, does that make sense ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One reason for running tests and coverage separately is, measuring coverage requires changing the program to support collecting coverage information.

In Java, both Jacoco and Cobertura will modify the bytecode of the class files to add instructions to record coverage. In C++, to use GCov to measure coverage you compile the binaries with different flags to those used to create release binaries.

Therefore, it makes sense to run the tests against the release artifacts to gain confidence that the release artifacts are behaving correctly. Then to measure coverage in a separate run against the instrumented artifacts.

It is, of course, possible to assume that the coverage enabled artifacts will be functionally equivalent to the release artifacts. Therefore, running tests twice is not required. This comes down to your (and your companies) attitude to risk and you can decide to run the tests twice (with and without coverage) or once with coverage enabled.

Comment: thanks for this explanation sure shed some light on the topic thank you.